# Malloc/Free based Memory Leak Undetected by Instruments?

Tags: ios, malloc, instruments, memory-leaks

I just found a memory leak in my code, caused by a C-style array of pointers that was not being freed.

The curious thing is, I tested my app in Instruments->Leaks quite thoroughly, but the leak was never detected (I just released version 1.0 last week, without any trouble so far).

Now I'm working on version 1.1 and just found the logical error. I fixed it and, so far there seems to be no 'over-release' crash and I'm confident the fix is due.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I always assumed that Objective-C's retain/release is just malloc/free under wraps, so leaks based on C memory functions should be equally visible to Instruments...?

Comment: Leaks is conservative, and unfortunately does not show all possible leaks. I've come to rely on heap shots in the Allocations instrument for a more reliable indicator of items accumulating in memory when they shouldn't be: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: I already knew it can't catch retain cycles (because there are references left to each object), but malloc'ed memory... I'm sure it does mot happen ALL the time...?

Comment: @Brad If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it.